# Bubble sort not sorting in Python

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I've started trying to use python again for some simple code, where before I've only really used p5.js. I'm trying to code a bubble sort and after making a working bubble sort, I copied part of the code into another code to implement into First Fit decreasing bin packing. Now with minimal changes, the sort isn't working where it would before. I only changed it to perform all bubble sorts until it is sorted instead of once at a time with user input in between. The new code does not sort the items correctly and often sorts the highest number on the list into the middle. I tried this with numbers including 108 and 20 and 108 was always after 20 even though it's a decreasing sort. The bubble function I use is

```
def bubble(x):
y = []
i = 0
k = 1
while i + k < len(x):
    if x[i] < x[i + k]:
        y.append(x[i + k])
        k = k + 1
    else:
        y.append(x[i])
        i = i + k
        k = 1
y.append(x[i])
return y
```

The original code is:

```
    numbers = []
len = int(input("How many numbers are there? "))

for i in range(0, len):
    current = str(i + 1)
    num = int(input("Number " + current + " "))
    numbers.append(num)

print("Here are your numbers:")
print(numbers)

bubbling = False

def bubble(x):
    y = []
    i = 0
    k = 1
    while i + k < len:
        if x[i] < x[i + k]:
            y.append(x[i + k])
            k = k + 1
        else:
            y.append(x[i])
            i = i + k
            k = 1
    y.append(x[i])
    return y

cont = input("Bubble? (Y/N) ")
if cont == "Y":
    bubbling = True

while bubbling == True:
    previous = numbers
    numbers = bubble(numbers)

    if numbers == previous:
        end = input("The bubble sort has been finished" )
        bubbling = False
        break

    print(numbers)

    cont = input("Bubble? (Y/N) ")

    if cont == "Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

and my second iteration is: (numbers are just input one at a time and enter nothing for it to bubble)

```
listing = True
bubbling = True

temp_array = []

# if an input is empty, stop adding numbers to the array and add bin size (LATER)

while listing:
    temp_number = input()
    if temp_number:
        temp_array.append(temp_number)
    else:
        listing = False
        break


print(temp_array)


def bubble(x):
    y = []
    i = 0
    k = 1
    while i + k < len(x):
        if x[i] < x[i + k]:
            y.append(x[i + k])
            k = k + 1
        else:
            y.append(x[i])
            i = i + k
            k = 1
    y.append(x[i])
    return y


while bubbling:
    prev_array = temp_array
    temp_array = bubble(prev_array)
    if temp_array == prev_array:
        bubbling = False
        break

print(temp_array)
```

Comment: First, can you give us a complete example? " I tried this with numbers including 108 and 20" isn't a complete example unless `bubble([108, 20])` actually returns `[20, 108]`, which it doesn't.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like your problem isn't in your bubble sort, but in your input. `temp_number = input()` will give you a string. If you sort the strings `'108'` and `'20'`, then `'20' > '108'`, because strings are compared character by character, dictionary-style: `'2' > '1'`, so `'20'` is bigger. You just need `temp_number = int(input())` or something similar somewhere. If you understand that and it's just a simple oversight, we can close this question as a typo; if you need further explanation, we can find a duplicate with a detailed answer.

Comment: As a side note, why are you implementing a bubble sort in the first place? If you're doing it as an exercise, you should probably write a test driver that compares `bubble(x)` to `sorted(x)` for a variety of different `x` lists. If you just need some numbers sorted, just call `sorted` instead of implementing your own less-efficient sort.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you very much, I wanted to make sure in the second version that not just integers could be included but forgot about string conversion.

Answer (score -2):

```
numbers = []
len = int(input("How many numbers are there? "))

for i in range(0, len):
    current = str(i + 1)
    num = int(input("Number " + current + " "))
    numbers.append(num)

print("Here are your numbers:")
print(numbers)

bubbling = False

def bubble(x):
    y = []
    i = 0
    k = 1
    while i + k < len:
        if x[i] < x[i + k]:
            y.append(x[i + k])
            k = k + 1
        else:
            y.append(x[i])
            i = i + k
            k = 1
    y.append(x[i])
    return y

cont = input("Bubble? (Y/N) ")
if cont == "Y":
    bubbling = True

while bubbling == True:
    previous = numbers
    numbers = bubble(numbers)

    if numbers == previous:
        end = input("The bubble sort has been finished" )
        bubbling = False
        break

    print(numbers)

    cont = input("Bubble? (Y/N) ")

    if cont == "Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Can you describe your question?